# check file size using javascript before uploading

Tags: javascript, filesize, activexobject

```
<html>
    <head>   
        <script>   
            function A()    
            {    
                var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");    
                var d = document.a.b.value;    
                var e = oas.getFile(d);    
                var f = e.size;    
                alert(f + " bytes");    
            }    
        </script>    
    </head>    
    <body>    
        <form name="a">    
            <input type="file" name="b">    
            <input type="button" name="c" value="SIZE" onClick="A();">    
        </form>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

this code is not working, i click the size button nothing is happen i checked ActiveXObject is not working 
i am using IE 
what is the reason for this

Comment: Please make things easier for people reading your question and **format your code**.

Comment: Most likely it does not work because you do not have access to the actual filename anymore in a file upload field. On a normal web page you will not be allowed to do this anyway. Perhaps Flash can help you. You should have continued reading http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=6704

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ActiveXObject` try this with `jQuery`

For the HTML bellow

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

try the following:

```
//binds to onchange event of your input field
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {

  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
  alert(this.files[0].size);

});
```

See following thread:

[How to check file input size with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery)