# How to select a file and load its binary content to a local variable (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I want to send a file in a REST PUT request. 
The user should be able to choose the file he wants to load from his local machine. I need to load the file as binary content and send it as part of the PUT request.

How can i let the user choose the file and load its binary content?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a form with the enctype of multipart/form-data and the method equals PUT

```
<form method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://myrestserver.com/">

User name: <input type="text" name="username" />
<br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
<br />
File to upload: <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!

</form>
```

Comment: I don't have all the data in the form. there are more parameters i should put on the request, including username and password

Comment: You can add as much data as you want as hidden fields - `<input type="hidden" name="username" value="the username" />` -  Although anything related to username and password should be handled by the server side for security reasons.

Comment: the user name and pass are inserted by the user, and are unknown. What i need is to be able to read the file as binary data to a local var (should work also in FF and IE)

Comment: So, that is it. the user name and the password are going to be text inputs. simple like that. I will edit the question with the inputs

Comment: I receive the login info earlier in other place. I want to send the file using Webdav protocol. what i need is the binary data of the file.

Comment: have you tried the webdav plugin for query? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/WebDAV

Comment: you can try something similar to what I've answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery/3937404#3937404 But, as browsers security policies can not be overriden by JS, the access to file system information might not work with some browsers, like IE