# Uploading file size check Grails

Tags: ajax, grails, file-upload

I am facing a problem regarding file uploading in Grails.
I would like to check the file size runtime after opening from the windows explorer and give me the error message if any condition fails.

I have a file uploading window where I have 3 file choose options. I would like to check each three files not to be more than 5MB. When I click on Browse button then my system explorer opens and I choose file.

Is there any way to check file size while selecting the file using javascript/ Ajax call? And if the file size is exceeds than the explorer show again to choose another file.

Comment: you can do this in HTML5 in a standard way, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: You can refer to the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/find-out-file-size-before-uploading-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About this issue, there is a plug-in called [file-uploader](http://www.grails.org/plugin/file-uploader) to the rescue.

With this plug-in you can define some restrictions in config.groovy. Here is an example:

```
fileuploader {
    avatar {
        maxSize = 1024 * 256 //256 kbytes
        allowedExtensions = ["jpg","jpeg","gif","png"]
        path = "/tmp/avatar/"
    }
    docs {
        maxSize = 1000 * 1024 * 4 //4 mbytes
        allowedExtensions = ["doc", "docx", "pdf", "rtf"]
        path = "/tmp/docs/"
    }
}
```