# MAX_FILE_SIZE not giving error?

Tags: php, html

I set a limit with a max of 10MB to uploads in my php code with

```
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1048576 * 10);
if ($_FILES['uploadphoto']['size'] > MAX_FILE_SIZE) { $errors[] = "Photo exceeds 10MB limit.";}
```

Which works fine. But I know you can put this;

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MAX_FILE_SIZE; ?>" />
```

In the form so that the user knows he uploaded a file too large instantly. This works but it doesn't give the user an error message that the file was too large. What can I do to show an error message?

Comment: Have you tried JavaScript?

Comment: @user2019515 I thought of using it but I don't know enough of it to use for this. Can you think of a solution using it?

Comment: See: https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&fp=540b244135372103&q=javascript%20form%20validation&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/find-out-file-size-before-uploading-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: If you specified `MAX_FILE_SIZE` on client side and client break that size, it would reflect in [`$_FILES["uploadphoto"]["error"]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about case 2!

```
switch($_FILES['uploadphoto']['error']) {

case 2:
echo 'Photo exceeds 10MB limit.';
break;
}
```

Thank you @Passerby!