# How to find number of files in html file type using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="true"/>
```

Here I upload 4 files.I want to find the length of files I uploaded using  javascript.

Comment: how are you uploading the files, what are you using, provide some code or anything!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading

Comment: just selecting multiple-files from brower prompt, and I want to find that number of files with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This method

`var numFiles = $("input:file", this)[0].files.length;`

http://jsfiddle.net/xvLAc/1/

Comment: do u need the size of the file...?