# How to attach an event to check the file size before upload on all input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-type

I would like to attach an event to all the input type="file" on my website to check if the file size is superior to 5mo, and if so block the upload and display a warning instead. Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check file input size with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just bind the change event with jQuery:

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
    var f=this.files[0];
    var sizeInMb = f.size/1024;
    var sizeLimit= 1024*5; // if you want 5 MB
    if (sizeInMb > sizeLimit) {
        alert('Sorry the file exceeds the maximum size of 5 MB!');
        // reset the input (code for all browser)
        this.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // go on
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it just a little because my input were dynamically generated by using $(document).on("change",'input[type=file]',function(event) and it works great

Answer (score 0):

you can try as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a3d5cpq1/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
<span class="err"></span>
```

**JS**

```
$('#myFile').on('change', function(e) {
   if((this.files[0].size/1000) > 5120)
   {
       $('.err').text('File size limit exceeded');
       e.preventDefault();
   }
   else
      $('.err').text('');
});
```