# How to get selector form fieldNode?

Tags: javascript, liferay

I try write custom validator for liferay to valid file size before upload.But i cant get file size from fieldNode.

Here is print fieldNode:

```
+++fieldNode:fieldNode:INPUT#_31_WAR_uploadportlet_avatarUpload yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1510909953942_944
```

And here print selector use document.getElementById:

```
+++selector:[object HTMLInputElement]
```

This selector not problem with get file size.

So what diffrent between fieldNode and normal selector ? And how get file size from fieldNode.

This important for write custom validator can reusable. Please help me.

Comment: Hava a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading

Comment: I did with jquery, but cant with aui validator. My problem post above. Hope you can help.

Comment: what version of Liferay are you on?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as the jQuery example shows. If you have the AUI node just do

```
fieldNode._node.files[0].size
```

Comment: I think validate, show message and  prevent before user upload a file too big is good way with user experience.