# R Shiny — get file size without uploading?

Tags: javascript, r, http, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a way to "peek" at the file size without uploading files to R Shiny?

Comment: uploading or downloading? `fileInput` is used for uploading

Comment: Upload, edited for clarity

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading) you can find a related question.

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal, I was wondering if anyone had a solution in R. If not I will adapt the javascript solution and post it here.

Comment: `file.size` will only work on the host. If you want to check the file size on the client side you need JS.

Comment: It is certainly not possible with the standard `fileInput` widget. The documentation states clearly, that the reactive value of the widget is only invalidated after an upload succeeded. There may however be upload widgets in other packages that have different functionality.
Note: If your goal is to restrict the file size for uploads, you can do so by setting the `options(shiny.maxRequestSize=...)` option.

Answer (score 8):

With suggestions provided by @ismirsehregal, we can modify the `fileInput` and add some JS to achieve your goal.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("check", NULL, buttonLabel = "Upload to check", placeholder = "Check File Size"),
    # remove progress bar since we are not truely uploading
    tags$style("#check .shiny-file-input-progress {display: none}"), 
    tags$script(
        "
        $('#check').on('change', function() {
          $(this)
            .parents('div.input-group')
            .find('.form-control')
            .attr('placeholder', `File size is ${this.files[0].size}`); // update text
            
          // If you want R server to also know the size, we can set up an input 
          Shiny.setInputValue('check_size', this.files[0].size)
          $(this).val(''); // this prevents shiny to takeover the file and upload the file
        });
        "
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe(print(input$check_size))
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This will get you the file size both on UI and server. Hope this is what you want.
[image]