# Get file input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line in HTML:

```
<input class="input-file" type="file" id="input-recipe-pic">
```

After a user selects a file to upload, and presses the submit button, I am trying to get the file they selected from the file input tag above. How can I get the file with javascript so I can later send it by AJAX to avoid a page reload?

Comment: provide some code please, jsfiddle may be

Comment: added the line of html, just a regular input tag for a file.

Comment: does this help? http://www.devrecipes.com/2009/07/13/ajax-style-file-upload-without-page-refresh/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery

Comment: swfupload works. http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not possible without iframe hacks until the advent of the HTML5 File API. Using the HTML5 File API, you can do

```
$(".input-file").change(function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        alert(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

Note that this will only work on browsers that support the HTML5 File API, such as Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There are many upload plug in you can use for example http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

You can navigate to source code and see how it's done.

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
    alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```