# Getting file input content with Fable

Tags: javascript, html, f#, fable-f#

I've seen [simple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821542/get-file-input-with-javascript) to read contents from a file input in JavaScript using HTML5 File API.

This is my `view` method, inside a small `fable-arch` app:

```
let view model =
    div [
        attribute "class" "files-form"
    ] [
        form [
            attribute "enctype" "multipart/form-data"
            attribute "action" "/feed"
            attribute "method" "post"
        ] [
            label [ attribute "for" "x_train" ] [ text "Training Features" ]
            input [
                attribute "id" "x_train"
                attribute "type" "file"
                onInput (fun e -> SetTrainingFeaturesFile (unbox e?target?value)) 
            ]
        ]
        model |> sprintf "%A" |> text
    ]
```

- Is there a simple way to capture the file content directly from F#?
- What is the minimum amount of interop fable code necessary to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the latest version of Fable, we now have access to `Browser.Dom.FileReader` and avoid using interop.

It is possible to write something like:

```
input 
    [ 
        Class "input"
        Type "file"
        OnInput (fun ev -> 
            let file = ev.target?files?(0)

            let reader = Browser.Dom.FileReader.Create()

            reader.onload <- fun evt ->
                dispatch (SaveFileContent evt.target?result)

            reader.onerror <- fun evt ->
                dispatch ErrorReadingFile

            reader.readAsText(file)
        ) 
    ]
```

[Live demo](https://fable.io/repl/#?code=LYewJgrgNgpgBAUSsAlgZwBYDoDKLgAOsAkgHYEQAuAUNQBQBUD1AsiqfgIZRycFEoAxp0ooQpOJhAB3dgHM4GGXEog4ENPCSpM1AJogIcYRIBm7MHFAAneO1NrOAI0OVEOjL2uCMKSjEFKCFteUks0TkJYNF43DEpKAjQALgB6VJhkdGw5PwwIJywxVOoGAEpaEAIYCQAxZ1gsAGEQWywAKTQyf2sq6iqauHqnRoAlGE5A-uq6hpgsccnKLAAFXqTpwe1szYltzAWJqYHZkfmW21p0uBYAeQARBAAZWkoAT2qb8Ey4AF5qOCAuAAbyGKFgLVI-ihcGSkko1nkcAAvq8PvAWGgFP8gXAAD5wJoYTikOQwABq3Ag8BApnhiNJAKBBJwnAAbjBauCYJDoW5afT5EzAQSENZetZFmB5FzYLRYG52H44HQyn8QWCIeI+eqAES6lEAGkJwDAWFI4hgV1ScAAqit7gBBAAqCHlMDcEAIYBE8DowCxyUxcjV-u+UCD4bVOKBwBEPisWLgskoGGF+LgrI5sp52pqbkEeZhAFoAHzp3GgnO8-PqwtQ2vI41NU3my20XGi8WtKUy7lwMsVoHXe5qNAgYAe3yM3G40BgTLN1sW0hW6jXcnEBAAdRVtjCMFslhTnkWgQq1AVcDZKBg0is4bg0rQBHjnhjgOlbLgAG1CVBODQGJdTjdhi3rShOHYQ8DQAXSHQE-wQ2d2AoNxkNnIEkMwnCcKaACgLgXVUKoXUMNwoFnXRIjzFgMiKIYuBblIMg0JVUwIAkGBvzLOByMYoEr1o+BfjgbisEg6wyUoAB+YS0BkugAAYLwEgSr1sTgF2sdUACFemkTRrCwUdgCwHMpUPZpNP8VUOzUhjNO0rBxCgEAtLgAAeYs4A4ri2TcQcHIc59X0oBM6CzTluRrGFuOWSTpJk2w0GgShVOC3CnKsy1ux07zfM4sSAoHctMoE0K30QPLe1JHN7PK2dsuMpzHTQZ0YAAD0oOhhIqRrATVfjZ3giqUG-P9RuCv80ARB8FygcyYqLNwpsw+D1xtR1+GoNYQDkaxIiwYAAGs9oOyI4CVT1vV9a9b2kag8VLOBzsOsyT0hcdYGdQ7BCtZ7Xt6C6PryM9KBwN5SB8XoLQ0IjMg8Ys+AIMjAbeo7rE46ggA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAUHUBTAhgE3gAm54ElgqbhgAOAtEgI4CuAlgG4C8A5AMID2AdmEj+QBUAnqSQtMAY268erXgA8wAenDQA3JJAoATgGcCTGmABm5ABwssOYLona6pMJl3aJTAEQB9TwAkA8gDKAt5KUHQARrpK2qgSYAB0pNocaDRxdNzxEHRc8QBWuu4wwEq29o5W2DZ2Dk4ubl6+gcGeoRFRMShx5GgcEInJqemZ2bkFRSVltfAlIKgYCMDhKUKSUCi6uh4opBRSPCg5SNpFcDi4aIyYdGgeSFDZuiDkO6Tuaxtb7vePz68TSkuDBmSmWaCE8EQKkgsDgQA&css=BYFwtgNgNAUARgewCYE8AEBvGadoGYIB2IAtAM4CWAXgKYBcaAjAGwAOAHgNwwC+MMAOjABDCoRIBjIiFGEaAJ0zZcSCmVYRhKBngg0uynAHcKSEMAaMADFYCk3XGmA0KAc1CWb9w2gBWAVzIQCjwUSWkaYgYJSJAFB1xhCDdxCjiwMmjY+J9dfRJVeRoJYKJohAh-MEJuPkExVn8QJUdWYSRVQlcGAQAmAFYisAScAmJyanomNgNHEzMLNAGrDhG0EXlXMRJEEBAEMEsh2pggA)

Answer (score 10):

> I couldn't find a way to not write plain JavaScript mainly because I couldn't import/instantiate `FileReader` from Fable. If someone can do it, then the solution can probably improve.

Reading the file is asynchronous. This means that the view should generate a delayed model update. Since that can only be done in the model update function, I had to forward a JavaScript File handle inside.

The plain JavaScript is just an export hack

```
// file interops.js, can I get rid of this?
export var getReader = function() { return new FileReader(); }
```

In the view

```
// view code
input [
    attribute "id" "x_train"
    attribute "type" "file"
    onInput (fun e -> FromFile (SetField, e?target?files?(0)))
]
```

So the message is actually a "Delayed Message with File Content". Here's the action and update code:

```
type Action =
    | SetField of string
    | FromFile of (string -> Action) * obj

let update model action =
    match action with
    | SetField content ->
        { model with Field = content}, []
    | FromFile (setAction, file) ->
        let delayedAction h =
            let getReader = importMember "../src/interops.js"
            let reader = getReader()
            reader?onload <- (fun () ->  h <| setAction !!reader?result)
            reader?readAsText file |> ignore
        model, delayedAction |> toActionList
```

The `FromFile` is a complex action because I want to use it to set more than one field. If you only need one, you can make it just an `of obj`.

Comment: Thanks @MangelMaxime for all the suggestions in the Fable channel. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on Maxime's answer, using Fable.Elmish.React v3.0.1. I'm not familiar with the ? operator, but I was able to cast some types using the :?> one instead.

```
input [
          Class "input"
          Type "file"
          OnInput (fun ev ->
            let file = (ev.target :?> Browser.Types.HTMLInputElement).files.Item(0)
            let reader = Browser.Dom.FileReader.Create()
            reader.onload <- fun evt ->
              (*
                Negotiate/assume the onload target is a FileReader
                Result is a string containg file contents:
                https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText
              *)
              dispatch (Set (string (evt.target :?> Browser.Types.FileReader).result))

            reader.onerror <- fun evt ->
              dispatch (Set "Error")
            
            reader.readAsText(file))]
```

Comment: `?` operator comes from the `open Fable.Core.JsInterop`