# check the file size using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check file input size with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery)

i need to check the uploaded image size is less than  5mb

i using the following code

```
$("#fileUpload").change(function () {

        $file = $("#fileUpload");
        var a = $file[0];

        var iSize = ($file[0].files[0].size / 1024);
        if (iSize / 1024 > 1) {
            iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100)
            alert('file size is ' + iSize);
            if (iSize > 5) {
                $('#FileImageSizeValidation').show();
            }

        }

    });
```

in that, i got the undefined error on $file[0].files[0]. it shows error in this line.
how to do this.

thanks 
pooja

Comment: Please Check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery

Comment: Make sure the browser support it.

Comment: i got it. in chrome it works fine. in IE , i got error.

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 and lower doesn't support the HTML5 File API so you cannot obtain the file size on the client. Make sure that you are using a browser that supports this API.