# How to get response on http request file upload aborted?

Tags: node.js, http, express, formidable

I'm going to upload a file using **nodejs** with **express**.

I see that bodyParser gets the job done...

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({"limit": '2mb'}));
```

But if I want to limit the size of the request I found that it doesn't cancel the upload somehow. The client keeps sending data.

So I wrote this middleware:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

   if(err.status == 413){
       req.destroy();
       return res.json({
            "status": 413,
            "message": err
       },413);
   }else
       next(err);
});
```

It works, cancels the upload but the client doesn't get (or ignore) the response!

I think this could be a behavior of the http protocol, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code should work, but don't destroy the request! Just delete `req.destroy();` line from your code.
You can also try something like this (it was working on my side) in order not to use middleware:

```
express = require 'express'
app = express()
swig = require 'swig'
cons = require 'consolidate'
swig.init {
  root: __dirname + '/views'
  allowErrors: true
}
app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'
app.set 'view options', {layout: false}
app.engine '.html', cons.swig
app.set 'view engine', 'html'

# set upload dir
app.use express.bodyParser {uploadDir: './upload'}

app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  res.render 'index.html', {}

app.post '/file-upload', (req, res) ->
  # you can get some info about files here (size, path, name, type)
  console.log req.files
  # check that size is good
  if req.files.thumbnail.size > 200
    res.send 413
  else
    res.send 'Uploaded!'

console.log 'listen port 3000'
app.listen 3000
```

And in form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file-upload">
<input type="file" name="thumbnail">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

[Look here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files) for details.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: That works... but my problem is when the file is too big...
I don't want to wait until the file is completely uploaded to reject it.

Comment: You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery) and [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-file-size-before-uploading-it) but you'll have problems in IE. Of course you should check file size on server too.