# Uploaded File Size Error On IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How to get uploaded file size using JavaScript or jQuery and using codes should be applicable whole browsers (IE,chrome, Firefox...etc)

```
<input id="id_file" type="file" class="attachefile" name="file" >


$("#id_file").live('change', function(){
  var size = $(this)[0].files[0].size;
  alert(size)
});
```

This code not working IE browser

Comment: define "not working". Any error ? Which IE version ?

Comment: No error's all the IE version's

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check file input size with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

A little research reveals that it is possible to restrict the file upload size using HTML5 File API.

Supported IE browser is **IE10+**

Check this [**Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)