# i want to get file size which i am uploading using html but it is not working

Tags: javascript, html

i want to get file size which i am uploading using html but it is not working.

Here is my Code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#myFile1").change(function() {
                    var f1 = document.getElementById("myFile1").value;
                    if ((f.size || f.fileSize) == 09765625)
                    {
                        alert("file size is less than 1mb");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("file size should not exceed more than 1mb");
                        $(this).val($.data(this, 'f'));
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

        })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type='file' name="file" id="myFile1" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("myFile1").value` is return only file name.

input file field is return file info in array so use `[0]` for first file, try this way

```
var file_size = document.getElementById("myFile1").files[0].size
```

Another issue: you have assigned Dom ref in `f1` variable and using `f` in `IF` condition.. use `f1` variable in condition, many bugs try this updated code

```
var f1 = document.getElementById("myFile1").files[0];
if (f1.file_size < 1048576)
{
   alert("file size is less than 1mb");
}
```

```js
$(function() {
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#myFile1").change(function() {
                    var f1 = document.getElementById("myFile1").files[0];
                    if (f1.file_size < 1048576)
                    {
                        alert("file size is less than 1mb");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("file size should not exceed more than 1mb");
                        $(this).val($.data(this, 'f'));
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' name="file" id="myFile1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `f`

instead of `f1`

```
var f = document.getElementById("myFile1");
```

As you're checking variable `f` in conditions. so change it accordingly

And you should check file size using following

```
var f = $("#myFile1")[0].files[0].size;
```

---

```
$("#myFile1").change(function() {
         var f1 = document.getElementById("myFile1").value; // will get file input value
         var size = ($("#myFile1")[0].files[0].size); // get file size here

         if (size < 1048576) {
             alert("file size is less than 1mb");
         } else {
             alert("file size should not exceed more than 1mb");
             $(this).val($.data(this, 'f'));
             return false;
         }
     });
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nu4uh8zn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed code as below.

---

```
    <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#myFile1").change(function() {
                    var f1 = this.files[0];
                    if (f1.size  < 1048576)
                    {
                        alert("file size is less than 1mb");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("file size should not exceed more than 1mb");
                        $(this).val($.data(this, 'f1'));
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

        })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type='file' name="file" id="myFile1" />
  </body>
</html>
```

---

You are doing incorrect DOM manipulations, better go with Jquery and try using some good online editors like [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic)

Also, naming convention must be taken care of like you declared **f1** variable and tried to use **f**

Also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery) this post.