# How to upload several files into different servers at a same time using html

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In my html form, I'm uploading a number of files to the server:

```
<form action="${uploadUrl}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="myFile" multiple>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

However, I want to add a condition on the size of the uploaded file. If the file is smaller than for example 1MB, I want to upload it to a different `uploadUrl` and if it is larger than that, I would like to upload it to another url. How can I achieve this? 
It gets more difficult when I'm uploading several files at a same time.

Comment: do you use any libraries such as `apache commons`

Comment: @SanKrish Yes. I can use it if necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery once you get the file size use the required url