# Jquery file size validation does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, validation

I got this jquery file type validation on the internet. It works great. I later added some code into it to validate file's size as well. But it did not raise alert box when my file size is greater than 50KB. I just learn jquery so I am not sure what i added is correct or not. Please help.

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/giangvy1011/q9L5w8k3/)

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$");
if(!(regex.test(val))) {
$(this).val('');
alert('Unsupported file');
} 
if ($(this).files.size > 50000 || $(this).files.fileSize > 50000)
    {
        //reset file upload control
       $(this).val('');
       //show an alert to the user
       alert('Allowed file size exceeded 50KB');


    }
}); });
</script>
```

This is what i have added into the existing code:

```
if ($(this).files.size > 50000 || $(this).files.fileSize > 50000)
    {
        //reset file upload control
       $(this).val('');
       //show an alert to the user
       alert('Allowed file size exceeded 50KB');


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5h29Lxv7/1/)

Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$");
if(!(regex.test(val))) {
$(this).val('');
alert('Unsupported file');
} 
if (this.files[0].size > 50000 || this.files[0].size > 50000)
    {
        //reset file upload control
       $(this).val('');
       //show an alert to the user
       alert('Allowed file size exceeded 50KB');


    }
}); });
```

Fore more refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery) . It uses`this.files[0].size` means get file size for 1st selectd file(If multiselect is enabled , checks for 1st image) ,anyway you are not having multiselect so you access it using 0th index of files selected because you can select only 1 file in regular operation.

Comment: What if I have 6 <input type='file'> in my form?

Comment: @GiangNguyen , no issue with multiple files .Check here => http://jsfiddle.net/5h29Lxv7/2/ .It just makes sure for each <input type="file> It checks for 1st selected file in case of multiselect.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$");
if(!(regex.test(val))) {
$(this).val('');
alert('Unsupported file');
} 
if (this.files[0].size > 50000)
    {
        //reset file upload control
       $(this).val('');
       //show an alert to the user
       alert('Allowed file size exceeded 50KB');


    }
}); });
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
```

Comment: I dont think its anyway different than answer i posted .

Comment: There is no need of  this.files[0].size > 50000 condition twice i think