# How to detect file size limits early when uploading with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have an ASP.Net MVC web application that needs to handle file uploading with progress.

To achieve this I have created a custom `IHttpHandler` that process the file stream in chunks using the `ProcessRequest` method. The implementation of this is not important for my issue.

Client side I am using JQuery to upload the file with the AJAX function, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.RouteUrl("Uploads")',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Filename': file.name },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    xhr: function () {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    $('progress').attr({
                        value: e.loaded,
                        max: e.total,
                    });
                }
            }, false);
        }
        myXhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            console.log('upload complete');
        });
        return myXhr;
    }
});
```

I have configured the upload/request limits in the web.config to allow files up to 2GB, which as far as I can tell is a hard limit in IIS anyway.

---

**Problem**

The problem I have is that when a user tries to upload a file larger than the limit it doesn't throw an error until the whole file has been transferred, which can take a few minute for large files. The is an undesired user experience for the user to have to wait for the transfer to complete before being told it cannot be processed.

---

**Question**

So my question is, is there anyway to get the ajax function to error as soon as the upload starts in the event the file is too large? Ideally I don't want the file to be sent to the server if it's only going to be rejected anyway.

---

**Additional Information**

For additional info, a breakpoint in the IHttpHandler code is only ever hit when the file size is within the limit, so I can't do anything in there to throw an error.

Note that I am **not** looking for a solution that involves checking the file size using javascript on the client size. Although I will probably use this as a user friendly precaution anyway, I want to find a method that causing the upload process to fail and abort before all the data is sent. I am however open to client side changes that don't rely on file size checking, for example alternate option for the ajax function.

I have also tried playing around with `Application_BeginRequest()` but this doesn't get called if the file is larger than 2GB, and I am not sure there is another event that I can check that happens before this.

Comment: Why you don't check file size before call ajax. You can check file size like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery)

Comment: @MinhNguyen: Yeah, it's an option I have consider, and I will probably also do something like that anyway. However, I would still like to find out if another solution can be found without relying on client side checks. Basically, I wan't to know if I can force the request to stop sending the data if it's only going to throw an error at the end anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can check your `formData` size before call your ajax.

```
var size = formData.get('fileName_key').size  // calculate your size accordingly

if(size>your_2gb_size) return false;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.RouteUrl("Uploads")',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Filename': file.name },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function () {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        $('progress').attr({
                            value: e.loaded,
                            max: e.total,
                        });
                    }
                }, false);
            }
            myXhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                console.log('upload complete');
            });
            return myXhr;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however I am looking for a solution that does not require checking the file size on the client side. I want my web application (server side) or IIS to throw an error and cause the upload to abort before all the data is sent.

Comment: Well, the server already has access to the file size. The problem is I don't have anywhere to check this during the process. the IHttpHandler code does not get executed when the file is too big. Possibly there is another place I can hook some code into, but I don't know where that is. That would be a possible solution if it can be done?