# Is there a way to add a default image to HttpPostedFileBase if user doesn`t upload one?

Tags: .net, image, model-view-controller, httppostedfilebase

I`m trying to add a default image from the ~/Content/Images/image.jpg to the HttpPostedFileBase if used doesn`t provide an image.

```
  if (imageRegisterView?.ContentLength == null)
                {
                    imageRegisterView.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/adult-1260380_640.jpg"));
                }
```

Comment: Why you want to add default image in  HttpPostedFileBase instead of that you can set a default image in server side, check when HttpPostedFileBase does not have the file so give is server default image path.

Comment: @AbhayAgarwal good point, I want to do something like that, it would be possible to show me how I will add that path to the server so that it will take that photo instead?

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery