# How to restrict upload file size in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How check file size on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084740/how-check-file-size-on-upload)

Ok, I got everything working and running, but now I need to restrict the file people send me via form to 500kb, at client side.
I understood you need a 3-party plugin?
Is there no way to do it via aspx?

If a plugin must be used: any suggestions to a good guide?

I'm using 3 files for my form: .aspx, .aspx.vb, web.config

If any other detail needed please let me know!
I'm stuck on this, one step away from finishing this form....

Thank you.

Comment: `ASP.NET AJAX TOOLKIT` may help you..

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do it via pure ASP.NET.

There a lots of commercial and non-commercial tools available. If your page is html 5, the easiest way to go might be to use [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/check-file-input-size-with-jquery).

If Flash is an option, check [swfupload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/).

[Here](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html) is a Javascript solution that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you set max upload in web.config. You can not check client-side without using a third-party tool.

Set it in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Problem is that you can't catch that client-side. You can however redirect the user if size is larger:

[Catching “Maximum request length exceeded”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Comment: this will restrict the total file size uploaded(instead of individual file size restriction [considering multiple file upload]) for entire website(rather than for a particular page particular file uploader), if I am not wrong..

Comment: a "multiple file upload" is still submitting one file at a time (unless using flash or the likes) storing it on the server temporarily. it's not packaging it client side and THEN uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength; 
 // Allow only files less than 512000 bytes (approximately 500kb (1024 = 1kb)(500*1024)) to be uploaded.            if (fileSize < 512000)            {
}
```