# Check size of uploaded file in mb

Tags: c#

I need to verify that a file upload by a user does not exceed 10mb.  Will this get the job done?

```
var fileSize = imageFile.ContentLength;
if ((fileSize * 131072) > 10)
{
    // image is too large
}
```

I've been looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084740/how-check-file-size-on-upload), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445861/validating-for-large-files-upon-upload)... but neither gets me all the way there.  I'm using [this](http://www.matisse.net/bitcalc/) as the conversion ratio.

`.ContentLength` gets the size in bytes.  Then I need to convert it to mb.

Comment: seriously?  Why the down votes?  You could at least say why.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you are given the size in bytes, you need to *divide* by `1048576` (i.e. `1024 * 1024`):

```
var fileSize = imageFile.ContentLength;
if ((fileSize / 1048576.0) > 10)
{
    // image is too large
}
```

But the calculation is a bit easier to read if you pre-calculate the number of bytes in 10mb:

```
private const int TenMegaBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024;


var fileSize = imageFile.ContentLength;
if ((fileSize > TenMegaBytes)
{
    // image is too large
}
```

Comment: But why 131072?

Comment: First examp!e is wrong still, because you perform integer division. So if file is 10.5mb - it will not get into image is too large branch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method to convert the `bytes` you got to MB:

```
static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
}
```

Comment: Was going to ask why this is a double, but that's a good call!

Answer (score 3):

Prefixes for multiples of bytes (B):
1024 bytes = 1kilobyte
1024 kilobyte =  1megabyte

```
double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
} 

var fileSize = imageFile.ContentLength;

if (ConvertBytesToMegabytes(fileSize ) > 10f)
{
    // image is too large
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fileSize = file.ContentLength;
if (fileSize > 10 * 1024 * 1024)
{
    // Do whatever..
}
```